# How to access arguments defined in "CAE Command Line Extra Args..." when using Abaqus PDE?

Tags: python, debugging, abaqus

I am trying to access the arguments defined in the menu option `Settings > CAE Command Line Extra Args...` when using Abaqus PDE to debug a Python script in `Kernel` environment.

I have tried to access the referred arguments using the `sys.argv` with no success. If I use the Abaqus PDE, `sys.argv` does not contain the values setted in the extra line arguments.

Extra line arguments:

[image: extra line arguments]

Watch list of `sys.argv`:
[image: watch variable]

However, everything goes as expected when I call the script without the Abaqus PDE (i.e. using extra line arguments after `--` in the command line as described in [documentation](https://help.3ds.com/2021/english/dssimulia_established/simacaecmdrefmap/simacmd-c-aclintintrointerface.htm?contextscope=all)).

Anyone has a clue of what I am doing wrong?